# java - library for performing cmd commands

Tags: java

i need a java library that gives the ability to perform cmd commands and retrieve the result.
it is preferable if this library can also perform cmd commands on remote computers (with given host, user, password).

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  jsch.xx.jar.  [Java secure channel](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) have abilities that you want.

Comment: Actually, this will connect a SSH server on some computer (which may be the same) and log in with some users' account, executing commands with the user's default shell. If this shell is `cmd`, this will do, but often (even on Windows computers), you will have a unix shell (like bash) there, if you have an SSH server at all. (This might be enough, though.)